# Is there anyway to read html file as excel or csv using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a Excel file in .xls extension, I cannot read as Excel using pd.read_excel, it will shows error as below.

`XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<table  '`

but if if I use pd.read_html, it can be read, however, it cannot read their positions and create a new DataFrame like pd.read_excel.

Can i know is there anyway to read this kind of file? or do i need to convert the file to Excel/CSV first? if so, may i know how?

Comment: It's easier if you bring it to csv and then convert to dataframe

Comment: you mean convert to csv first is it? how yaa?

Comment: extract data using html and populate to the csv

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone saved html file as xls, try opening that file in a text editor first and have a look.